# Unknown Column in subquery where contain INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables:

1. b2 table

[image: b2 table]

2. tb_stok table
   [image: tb_stok table]
3. tb_barang table
   [image: tb_barang table]

I intend to display the transaction_id column in the tb_stok table with 1 more column next to it called id_transaction which contains a sequence of numbers 1,2,3 and so on. I've tried this sql code and managed to produce a table like this:

```
SELECT @n := @n +1 id_transaksi, transaksi_id as kode_transaksi 
         FROM tb_stok, (SELECT @n := 0) m  
         WHERE tb_stok.tgl BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-07' AS DATE) AND
               CAST('2018-01-08' AS DATE)
```

[image: subquery table]

then I intend to display nama_b2 of b2 referenced in the result_transaction of the code above using a subquery like this:

```
SELECT b2.nama_b2 AS nama_barang 
FROM tb_stok INNER JOIN 
     tb_barang 
     ON tb_stok.kode_barang = tb_barang.kode_barang JOIN 
     b2 
     ON tb_barang.b2 = b2.b2_id 
WHERE tb_stok.id_transaksi='1' IN 
        (SELECT @n := @n +1 id_transaksi, transaksi_id as kode_transaksi 
         FROM tb_stok, (SELECT @n := 0) m  
         WHERE tb_stok.tgl BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-07' AS DATE) AND
               CAST('2018-01-08' AS DATE)
        )
```

I get error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'tb_stok.kode_transaksi' in 'where clause'

what is the correct code?

Comment: DO you have the table schema available??

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  There may be simpler approaches.

Comment: @GordonLinoff wait a minute, I'll edit it

Comment: @apomene wait a minute, I'll edit it

Comment: What is the purpose of IN? Which column do you want to compare to the subquery of IN and to which column of that subquery?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT b2.nama_b2 AS nama_barang 
FROM tb_stok INNER JOIN 
     tb_barang 
     ON tb_stok.kode_barang = tb_barang.kode_barang JOIN 
     b2 
     ON tb_barang.b2 = b2.b2_id 
WHERE tb_stok.id_transaksi  ='1' AND
      tb_stok.id_transaksi IN  
        (SELECT s2.transaksi_id
         FROM tb_stok s2 
         WHERE s2.tgl BETWEEN '2018-01-07'AND '2018-01-08' 
        )
```